# триггер неправильно считает поле Price

Tags: mysql, sql

Создаю следующий триггер на инсерт в таблице product_party_arrival(партия прихода товара). Партия прихода товара связана с конкретным размером и конкретным товаром поэтому делаю join на двух условиях. Триггер узнаёт цену товара и выставляет значение в поле Price значением равным произведению поля Count этой таблицы с полем CurrentPrice таблицы Product(Товар). Триггер выставляет то же значение что в поле Count. Вот сам триггер и результаты вставки. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот значения в промежуточной таблице с размерами и товарами. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Product:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @prices:=0;
SELECT CurrentPrice*NEW.count 
INTO @prices 
FROM mydb.product p
-- остальной текст запроса
;
SET NEW.price:=@prices;
-- ...
END;
```

Comment: выдаёт следующую ошибку
ERROR 1172: 1172: Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: всё верно, только после селекта ещё distinct поставить. Спасибо)

Comment: @user9115395 Это уже следствие особенностей Вашего набора данных. *после селекта ещё distinct поставить* Поскольку данные "кривые", DISTINCT может не спасти. Решение - замените `CurrentPrice` на, скажем, `MAX(CurrentPrice)`.